# Contraction and operator norm

Tags: matrices, analysis, normed-spaces

Hi there I am stuck at this problem. Let $T\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ be as follows: 
\begin{gather}
 T
 =
 \ 
  \begin{bmatrix}
   a &
   c \\
   0 &
   a 
   \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}
Show that if $|a|<1$ and $|c|\le1-|a|^2$, then $T$ is a contraction.

Here is what I have so far: Since $|c|^2\le 1-2|a|^2+|a|^4$, it follows that

$$‖T‖^2≤(2|a|^2+|c|^2)\le1+a^4.$$

What steps should be taken to show that $‖T‖\le1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2$,

$$||T\left(z_1,z_2\right)||^2=|az_1+cz_2|^2+|az_2|^2\leq|az_1|^2+|cz_2|^2+|az_2|^2$$

Now I suggest you use $|c|^2\leq 1-|a|^2$ first and see if you can simplify things.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I think I got it now!